# Did Patrick Stewart appear as an uncredited extra in this episode of Stargate Atlantis?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

In Stargate: Atlantis, Season 1, Episode 8 "Underground," Major Shepard's team meet the Genii. This marks the first appearance of Colm Meaney (Chief O'Brien on Star Trek: TNG) as Cowen, leader of the Genii.

Near the end of the episode, Cowen orders his men from hiding to surround Major Shepard and his team. As one of those soldiers moves into place, we get a pretty tight close-up. I swear it's Patrick Stewart. However, I can't find anything from IMDB, Stargate's wiki, or other internet sources to confirm this.

Was that Patrick Stewart, or just a guy who looks like Patrick Stewart? This [badly ripped video from youtube](https://youtu.be/2a56p17sIpE?t=2495) is all I could find to provide a link for, but pausing on my DVD gives a clear picture, and I swear it's him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actor appears to be [Nicolas W. Von Zill](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Nicolas_W._Von_Zill); so not Patrick Stewart.

[image: Image of Nicolas W. Von Zill, Stargate Atlantis]

<sub>[Image Source](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Nicolas_W._Von_Zill)</sub>

Comment: Wow. Thanks. What's the record for longest wait for answers? I would've checked sooner, but I tend to stay away from this stackexchange. Even the question topics had become too spoiler-ridden for me a few year back. But well answered, sir. Upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 15):

I reviewed my blu-ray copies and can say that the answer is no.   Please see this attached, HD screen grab.   Perhaps the low res version could pass, but not in glorious high definition!

[image: ScreengrabHD]

Comment: Fair to say that is definitively _not_ Patrick Stewart.

Answer (score 0):

No, Patrick Stewart had never been on any Star Gate series to date. Not only would it have been widely publicized, but it would have been a waste of a great actor to have him as a non-speaking blink and you'll miss it background character role. No matter how many Star Trek connections SGA had.

Comment: logical answer, but how can you say for certain?

Comment: @DustinDavis you want me to prove a negative? But let's put it this way, Patrick Stewart does not just walk on a set without a million people noticing it. There is 0.000000% chance that it would go unnoticed for what, a decade now?